# How to display Form data on click without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

After filling in the form inputs, When i press the calculate button on the form the result does not get displayed in the salary slip box(At the bottom of the box).

But when i do refresh the page and then press the calculate button the results do get displayed in the box.

Here is the link to the code:
[JsfiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/ofgrqwbn/)

```
"use strict";

const employeeName = document.querySelector("#input-name").value;
const grossPay = document.querySelector("#input-pay").value;
const bonus = document.querySelector("#input-bonus").value;
const allowance = document.querySelector("#input-allowance").value;
const incomeTax = document.querySelector("#input-tax").value;
const ei = document.querySelector("#input-ei").value;
const cpp = document.querySelector("#input-cpp").value;
const selectGender = document.querySelector(
  'input[name="gender"]:checked'
).value;
const selectDependent = document.querySelector(
  'input[name="dependent"]:checked'
).value;
const btnCalculate = document.querySelector("#submit");
const btnClear = document.querySelector("#clear");
const myForm = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
let inputAll = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function addition(bonus, allowance) {
  let total = Number(bonus) + Number(allowance);
  return total;
}
function deduction(ei, cpp) {
  let total = (Number(ei) + Number(cpp)) / 100;
  return total;
}

// console.log(addition(bonus, allowance));
// console.log(deduction(incomeTax, ei, cpp));

// gross salary plus additions minus deductions
// if female employee then minus 1%
// else deduction is 0

// if dependents === 2 then no deductions
// if dependents === 3 then 2 % deduction
// else if dependents === 4 then 4% deductions

// display the results on the salary slip

function genderDeduction(selectGender) {
  return selectGender === "Female" ? 0.01 : null;
}

function dependentDeduction(selectDependent) {
  if (selectDependent === "1") {
    return null;
  } else if (selectDependent === "2") {
    return 0.02;
  } else if (selectDependent === "3") {
    return 0.04;
  }
}

function incomeTaxDeduction(incomeTax) {
  return Number(incomeTax) / 100;
}
// console.log(genderDeduction("Female"));
// console.log(dependentDeduction("2"));

let totalAdditions = addition(bonus, allowance);
let totalDeductions = Number(
  grossPay * deduction(ei, cpp) +
    grossPay *
      (incomeTaxDeduction(incomeTax) -
        genderDeduction(selectGender) -
        dependentDeduction(selectDependent))
);

totalDeductions.toFixed(2);
function finalSalary(grossPay) {
  return Number(grossPay) + totalAdditions - totalDeductions;
}

const nameSlip = document.querySelector(".name");

const grossSalary = document.querySelector(".gross-salary");

const sumOfAdditions = document.querySelector(".total-additions");

const sumOfDeductions = document.querySelector(".total-deductions");

const netSalary = document.querySelector(".final-salary");

// function salarySlip() {}

// function clearInput() {
//   employeeName = "";
//   grossPay = "";
// }

btnCalculate.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  nameSlip.innerText = employeeName;
  grossSalary.innerText = `$ ${grossPay}`;
  sumOfAdditions.innerText = `$ ${totalAdditions}`;
  sumOfDeductions.innerText = `$ ${totalDeductions.toFixed(2)}`;
  netSalary.innerText = `$ ${finalSalary(grossPay)}`;
});

// btnClear.addEventListener("click", () => {
//   myForm.reset();
// });
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. `Uncaught ReferenceError: clearInput is not defined"`

Answer (score 0):

You have the following declaration:

```
<button
      onclick="clearInput"
      id="submit"
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary"
    >
      Calculate
    </button>
```

So you have to declare a function called "clearInput" to handle the button click event.

To solve your problem, you can modify the above declaration as below:

```
<button
      id="submit"
      type="submit"
      class="btn btn-primary"
    >
      Calculate
    </button>
```

And then add the below statements.

```
let myForm=document.getElementById("my-form");
myForm.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
    //do your work here
    e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work.

Comment: Would you help to update your code?

Comment: Tried it, it just refreshes the form and does not give me any values.

Answer (score 0):

I've partially updated your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/y7hbnv18/1/

what I did:

- updated all inputs to have a `name` property.
- created a reference to the `<form />` element in JS
- updated the listener on submit button to be on the form instead
- used the `FormData` API to retrieve the data from the form.

it's still somewhat in a broken state, in the last few fields, but I think you'll figure it out from here.

Comment: Yes, it is partially working right now.Thanks. I tried to fix the code but it gives me null on few of the fields. https://jsfiddle.net/samre/abtcxpgn/13/

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm not gonna fix the whole thing for you, but good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code that gets the values to the body of the event handler function.

```
btnCalculate.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const employeeName = document.querySelector("#input-name").value;
  const grossPay = document.querySelector("#input-pay").value;
  const bonus = document.querySelector("#input-bonus").value;
  const allowance = document.querySelector("#input-allowance").value;
  const incomeTax = document.querySelector("#input-tax").value;
  const ei = document.querySelector("#input-ei").value;
  const cpp = document.querySelector("#input-cpp").value;
  const selectGender = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="gender"]:checked'
  ).value;
  const selectDependent = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="dependent"]:checked'
  ).value;

  let totalAdditions = addition(bonus, allowance);

  let totalDeductions = Number(
    grossPay * deduction(ei, cpp) +
      grossPay *
        (incomeTaxDeduction(incomeTax) -
          genderDeduction(selectGender) -
          dependentDeduction(selectDependent))
  );
  totalDeductions.toFixed(2);

  nameSlip.innerText = employeeName;
  grossSalary.innerText = `$ ${grossPay}`;
  sumOfAdditions.innerText = `$ ${totalAdditions}`;
  sumOfDeductions.innerText = `$ ${totalDeductions.toFixed(2)}`;
  netSalary.innerText = `$ ${finalSalary(grossPay, totalAdditions, totalDeductions)}`;
});
```

Also update the `finalSalary` function so you can pass in `totalAdditions` and `totalDeductions` the signature should be

```
function finalSalary(grossPay, totalAdditions, totalDeductions)
```

You may also need to change the button type to `button` from `submit` to stop the form being submitted as this will refresh the page.

```
<button
  onclick="clearInput"
  id="submit"
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary"
>
Calculate
</button>
```